# MySQL - Prepared statements not returning full query

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

Im using prepare statement inside the stored procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS test;
delimiter //
  CREATE PROCEDURE
    test(IN query varchar(100))
  begin     
        SET @query =CONCAT('select * FROM db.',query,' LIMIT  10000;');
        select @query;
        PREPARE arcive_stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE arcive_stmt;
   commit;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE arcive_stmt;
 END //
delimiter ;
```

This procedure will get the table and where condition from user input and run the select query.

So I executed this:

```
mysql> call test ('logs where created_date < DATE(Now() - INTERVAL 3 month) and updated_at < DATE(Now() - INTERVAL 3 month');
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT  10000' at line 1
```

The I used print @query to debug this. Then its truncating my input string.

```
select * FROM db.logs where created_date < DATE(Now() - INTERVAL 3 month) and updated_at < DATE(Now() - INTER LIMIT  10000;
```

Its truncated my sting till `DATE(Now() - INTER`.
can someone help me to understand and fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IN` parameter length is set to 100 only. While your query string input is much more than character length of 100.

Increase it to a bigger value, let's say: 255

```
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS test;
delimiter //
  CREATE PROCEDURE
    test(IN query varchar(255))  -- increase to a bigger value
  begin     
        SET @query =CONCAT('select * FROM db.',query,' LIMIT  10000;');
        select @query;
        PREPARE arcive_stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE arcive_stmt;
   commit;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE arcive_stmt;
 END //
delimiter ;
```

On another note: Your input `query` string was not specifying `ORDER BY` clause. Do note that data is stored in unordered manner. Without `ORDER BY` clause, results obtained by `LIMIT..` will not be deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

you declared the procedure to take a string that is 100 characters long

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
  test(IN query varchar(100)) <-- ONE HUNDRED CHARS LIMIT
```